# The checked Gridview position changes on scrolling

Tags: android, gridview

I have already tried the suggestions which are there on this site and they dont work for me. I will try to be very precise. I have a Custom gallery which displays images in gridview. The user can select multiple images from the gridview. Once the Gridview position is clicked the "Tick" icon is displayed on that position to notify user that the image has been selected. The problem is when i select an image and scroll the "Ticked" icon which was on the selected image appears on some other image.Here is the code.

```
    public class CustomPhotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private GridView grdImages;
private Button btnSelect;

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;
private Cursor imagecursor = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
    grdImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);

        Log.e("arrPath", "" + arrPath[i]);
    }
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(arrPath);
    grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String[] arrPath;

    public ImageAdapter(String[] arrPath) {
        this.arrPath = arrPath;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return arrPath.length;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rootView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);
            rootView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rootView.getTag();

        }
        holder.chkImage.setId(position);
        holder.imgThumb.setId(position);
        holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.chkImage.getId()
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        Picasso.with(CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.this)
                .load(new File(arrPath[position]))
                .resize(150, 150)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imgThumb);
        return rootView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    ImageView chkImage;
    int id;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this it worked for me,

```
public class CustomPhotoGalleryActivity extends Activity {

private GridView grdImages;
private Button btnSelect;

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
private String[] arrPath;
private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
private int ids[];
private int count;
private Cursor imagecursor = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_gallery);
    grdImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdImages);
    btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
    imagecursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
    this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
    this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
    ids = new int[count];
    this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
    ArrayList<Items> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
        ids[i] = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
        int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       // arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
       Items items=new Items();
       items.setChkImage(youResourceId);
       items.setThumbImageUrl(imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
       items.setIsImageSelected(false);
       list.add(items);

        Log.e("arrPath", "" + arrPath[i]);
    }
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(list);
    grdImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
                    cnt++;
                    selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
                }
            }
            if (cnt == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ArrayList<Items> list;

    public ImageAdapter(ArrayList<Items> list) {
        this.arrPath = arrPath;
        this.list=list;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return arrPath.length;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Items getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item, null);
            holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumb);
            holder.chkImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkImage);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        if(list.get(postion).isImageSelected()){
           holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }else{
           holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }         

        holder.imgThumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = holder.chkImage.getId()
                if (list.get(postion).isImageSelected()) {
                    holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    list.get(postion).setIsImageSelected(false);
                } else {
                    holder.chkImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    list.get(postion).setIsImageSelected(true);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        Picasso.with(CustomPhotoGalleryActivity.this)
                .load(list.get(position).getThumbImageUrl())
                .resize(150, 150)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imgThumb);
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgThumb;
    ImageView chkImage;
    int id;
}
}

public class Items {


    int chkImage;
    String thumbImageUrl;
    boolean isImageSelected;


    public int getChkImage() {
        return chkImage;
    }

    public void setChkImage(int chkImage) {
        this.chkImage = chkImage;
    }

    public String getThumbImageUrl() {
        return thumbImageUrl;
    }

    public void setThumbImageUrl(String thumbImageUrl) {
        this.thumbImageUrl = thumbImageUrl;
    }

    public boolean isImageSelected() {
        return isImageSelected;
    }

    public void setIsImageSelected(boolean isImageSelected) {
        this.isImageSelected = isImageSelected;
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you faced??

Comment: Suppose I select the image in the 0th position of gridview it gets "Ticked". And when i scroll down automatically few images below also get the ticked and the 0th position image which was ticked earlier gets unticked

Comment: Thank you ! Its working now.. I missed a part of the code you gave :)

Comment: The relevant code should really be highlighted. While the specific code block may resolve the issue, there is no explanation.